# Getting The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection error with c# / ASP.net app

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a generic method which is adding parameters to a cmd.parameters collection. I am getting the following error when 2 people are hitting the same stored procedure at the same time:

The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

I have already searched within StackOverflow and also elsewhere on the web but so far I am not able to rectify the problem. My code is as follows:

```
protected DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string StoredProcName, List<TParameter> Params) {
bool internalOpen = false;
DataSet resultDataSet = null;
TDataAdapter dataAdapter;
TCommand cmd;

try {
    resultDataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter = new TDataAdapter();
    cmd = new TCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = StoredProcName;

    if (transaction != null) {
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.Connection = transaction.Connection;
    } else {
        cmd.Connection = connection;
    }

    if (Params != null && Params.Count > 0) {
        foreach (TParameter param in Params) {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
    }

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
        connection.Open();
        internalOpen = true;
    }

    dataAdapter.Fill(resultDataSet);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    return resultDataSet;
} catch {
    throw;
} finally {
    if (internalOpen) {
        connection.Close();
    }

}
```

The error is happening during the foreach loop but despite clearing parameters and applying some other attempted fixes I have been unable to prevent this error from happening.

This is being called from another method using the following:

```
 result = base.ExecuteDataSet(procName,this.ConvertArrayList(this.ParamsList));
```

It is an older c# / asp.net (web forms) application that I am using, so the code reflects this.

The error message begins like so:

> [ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Validate(Int32 index, Object value) +5955779
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(Object value) +34

I am testing using 2 browsers logging in as 2 users at the same time and clicking a link to a page which pulls multiple records. One of these users gets the error while the other gets the correct page with returned results as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. Apologies if I haven't explained this well enough but I've been looking at this all day and haven't been able to progress.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The ParamsList is set/get like this:

```
public ArrayList ParamsList {
        get {
            //Check to see if the parameters list has been initialised.
            if (m_paramsList == null) {
                //Create a new empty parameters list to pass back.
                m_paramsList = new ArrayList();
            }
            return m_paramsList;
        }
        set {
            m_paramsList = value;
        }
    }
```

And populated like so:

```
internal void AddParameter(string name, string value) {
        IDbDataParameter param = CreateStringParameter(name);

        param.Value = GetValueFromString(value);

        Dal.ParamsList.Add(param);
    }
```

for every type of parameter type....

internal void AddParameter(string name, double? value) {

internal void AddParameter(string name, byte[] value) {

etc...

Comment: What are TCommand and TParameter? Some sort of child class of SqlCommand/SqlParameter?

Comment: The are basically generic sqlcommand and sqlparameter - this layer was able to use both Oracle and SQL but now we only use SQL - although still using this old generic layer. Look at them as sql equivalents. So yes, they are child classes as you say.

Comment: you know the `Fill()` function will open and close the connection automatically, right? when using `Fill()`, there's no need to worry about calling `connection.Close()`, and therefore the entire try/catch block can be removed without any loss of functionality.

Comment: Also, it's _very poor practice_ to store a connection object in your data access class for re-use, because it breaks connection pooling. You can store a transaction, which implies a connection, but otherwise you really do want a _brand new connection variable_ for most queries, where you only keep the connection _string_ in your data access class.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks Joel. I will refactor a bit but you are right. I also think the explicit connections opening/closing are not helping.

Comment: See source code #region Protected & Public Methods : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,2a030fac9c5703ba

Comment: Why did you add `catch { throw; }`? Honest question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the code in the question... a lot of it didn't accomplish what the author likely intended. The try/catch/finally, for example, was completely worthless because the catch block just re-threw the same exception and using the `Fill()` method meant the finally block was not needed. Other code has similar issues.

Except for the transactions,  you could reduce the code down to just this, assuming `TCommand` and company fully implement the ADO.Net providers, where the reduced code actually *increases* performance, safety, and utility:

```
protected DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string StoredProcName, IEnumerable<TParameter> Params = null) 
{    
    DataSet resultDataSet = new DataSet();
    using (var cn = new TConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new TCommand(StoredProcName, cn))
    using (var adapter = new TAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (Params != null) 
        {
            foreach (TParameter param in Params)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
        }    
        adapter.Fill(resultDataSet);
    }
    return resultDataSet;        
}
```

But we *do* have that `transaction` value, and that's enough to break the `using` pattern here. Because of that, you'll want to effectively double the code length, to account for both variants. Yes, **the `using` pattern really is that important**, that you would effectively double the code length to keep it where possible:

```
protected DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string StoredProcName, IEnumerable<TParameter> Params = null) 
{  
    DataSet resultDataSet = new DataSet(); 
    if (transaction == null)
    { 
        using (var cn = new TConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new TCommand(StoredProcName, cn))
        using (var adapter = new TAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (Params != null) 
            {
                foreach (TParameter param in Params)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
            }    
            adapter.Fill(resultDataSet);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (var cmd = new TCommand(StoredProcName, transaction.Connection))
        using (var adapter = new TAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (Params != null) 
            {
                foreach (TParameter param in Params)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
            }    
            adapter.Fill(resultDataSet);
        }
    }
    return resultDataSet; 
}
```

Finally, *none of this will fix your problem*. The problem you're seeing is caused by code elsewhere trying too hard to re-use Parameter objects. You'll need to look at other code to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that TCommand is a type of SqlCommand, and TParameter is a type of SqlParameter. I think the problem is here:

```
    foreach (TParameter param in Params) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
```

param is a member of Params, which is a reference type; this means that you will potentially be sharing the same list of Params between multiple calls to ExecuteDataSet. Instead, do something like this:

```
    foreach (TParameter param in Params) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.ParameterName, param.SqlDbType, param.Size)).Value = param.Value;
    }
```

Also, you could be potentially sharing the same SqlConnection between multiple threads, which could be a problem. Generally I would recommend creating a new SqlConnection within the ExecuteDataSet method. The new SqlConnection will still be able to enlist within any in-flight transaction.

Finally, use "using" blocks for all IDisposable objects, e.g., SqlCommand, SqlCommand, DataSet etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the objects in `this.ParamsList` are being reused for every query. If you show how that list is defined and populated, we can confirm, but that's what it sounds like.

The solution is basically not to do that. Rebuild the parameter list with brand new `SqlParameter` objects for each query.

Otherwise you would have to employ some kind of locking to make sure two requests are not executed at the same time, but that seems like a worse solution.